# "Library not registered" error, can I determine which one exactly?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, outlook-addin

In C++ add-in for Outlook, I'm now getting "Library not registered" error. This add-in worked for ages on this machine but somehow things got broken now (although it still works fine on other machines).

Is there any way to find out which particular library is missing (not registered) without reinstalling everything? Is there a WinAPI call with some extended error information, such as the library name/path in question?

```
CComGITPtr< Outlook::_Application > m_GITPointer;
...
hr = m_GITPointer.CopyTo( &application ); // hr is 0x8002801d
```

Comment: think that not exist any api which give you extended error information here. only use debugger, for see what fail. this is usually related to *tlb* missing registration

Comment: Thanks. Can Visual Studio (e.g 2008) integrated debugger help me in this? Or do I need to setup some specialized debugger?

Comment: this very depended from your personal debugging skills.  Visual Studio  integrated debugger of course can help, but can be not simply. trace call  *CopyTo* manually can be long and hard. try set bp on *ZwOpenKey[Ex]* and *ZwCreateKey* for view what call fail..

Comment: this can be similar [this error](https://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/support/support_gsyncit_8002801D.shtml) - but need look under debugger which key fail *typelib* subkey fail to open

Comment: Reinstall Office to get the registry damage repaired.

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, but I already did this before asking this question.

Comment: You could also run [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to look for failed "Load Image" operation.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, I first reinstalled Office and it didn't help. Neither advice from RbMm did. However, when I completed both (first, uninstall, then manual registry repair), it worked!